# Changing the names of images within a directory and displaying the changed file names

Tags: php, arrays, opendir

The purpose of the script is to change the names of of a list of images within a directory for an ecommerce site. So specifically when the script is rand a user will type in a word or phrase that they would like a set or list of files to be prefixed with. The script will iterate over each file changing the prefix and appending the next available number starting from zero.

I'd like to display/render on the page to the user what files have been changed. right now when the script is ran it displays the current files within the directory, and then it list the changed files and their names within the directory.

How can i get the file list only to display when the script has finish processing the new names?

Why does the script not append the proper incremented number to the file name? It renames files the following order:
abc0.jpg
abc1.jpg
abc10.jpg
abc11.jpg
abc12.jpg
abc13.jpg

```
<?php 
  $display_file_list;

    //Allow user to put choose name
  if (isset($_POST['file_prefix'])){

    $the_user_prefix = $_POST['file_prefix'];


   //open the current directory change this to modify where you are looking
   $dir = opendir('.');

   $i=0;

   //Loop though all the files in the directory 
   while(false !==($file = readdir($dir)))
   {

    //This is the way we would like the page to function 

    //if the extention is .jpg
    if(strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) =='jpg')
    {
      //Put the JPG files in an array to display to the user
      $display_file_list[]= $file;

      //Do the rename based on the current iteration
      $newName = $the_user_prefix.$i . '.jpg';
      rename($file, $newName);
      //increase for the next loop
      $i++;
    }

       }



     //close the directory handle
     closedir($dir);

      }else{

    echo "No file prefix provided";
  }




?>

    <html>
    <body>
     <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="file_prefix"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submitMe">
    </form>
    </body>

</html>

<?php
  foreach ($display_file_list as $key => $value) {
           echo  $value. "<br>";
         } 


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

"How can i get the file list only to display when the script has finish processing the new names?"

I think this will work for you;

```
$path  = "path/to/files";
$files = glob("{$path}/*.jpg");
$files_renamed = array();
foreach ($files as $i => $file) {
    $name = "{$path}/{$prefix}{$i}.jpg";
    if (true === rename($file)) {
        $files_renamed[] = $name;
    }
}
print_r($files_renamed);
```